# Main class in Jar file from src/test

Tags: java, gradle, testng

I need to distribute one of our integration tests, it lives under src/test. So I'm using gradle to build a jar pointing to this class.

I figured this out from poking around the net:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
  zip64 = true
  manifest {
    attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
            'Implementation-Version': 1.3,
            'Main-Class': 'org.example.AnIntegrationTest'
  }
  from sourceSets.test.output
}
```

When I try running this I get the:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.example.AnIntegrationTest
```

The main method is there, and 'jar tf' does show me the class in the package.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you using `java -jar YourFatJar.jar` to run it??

Comment: Yup, here's the full command/output:
    java -jar build/libs/fatJar.jar
 Error: Could not find or load main class org.example.AnIntegrationTest

    jar tf build/libs/fatJar.jar | grep AnIntegration
 org/example/AnIntegrationTest.class
 org/example/AnIntegrationTest$ParallelUpload.class.class

Comment: You're missing dependencies. I imagine your test jar needs classes from your main jar?

Comment: Yup, when I run it from IntelliJ it works fine. So I thought missing dependencies would show up earlier ie during compile?

Comment: The dependencies are available during compile time because intelliJ/gradle provides them. After you package the Jar and run it using java, java by itself does not know where to look for dependencies. You can either place all dependencies (including transitives) in the same folder as your integ-test jar, and add the dependency line to manifest, or you can package all dependencies inside your integ-jar to produce one self-contained executable jar.

Comment: In fact you're calling your task fatjar, so I'm guessing you got that code from somewhere that was trying to package everything into one very "Fat" jar. Except you're missing the additional `from` line to add dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jar file is missing test-runtime dependencies. One possible solution is to package all required dependencies into your jar as well. Note that this will increase the size of your distributable jar.

Add an additional `from` clause to your jar task:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
  zip64 = true
  manifest {
    attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
            'Implementation-Version': 1.3,
            'Main-Class': 'org.example.AnIntegrationTest'
  }
  from sourceSets.test.output

  //collect all dependencies
  from { configurations.testRuntime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
  with jar
}
```

Comment: Damm, that looked promising. Din't work unfortunately. Same problem. I did get a much larger jar. And I do have classes from both main/ & test/ in the jar.

Comment: oops, i have the wrong config, should be `testRuntime`, unless if you have a separate config for integ-tests?

Comment: I don't understand? You have testRuntime in your example. I don't think I got another config for integration, although I'm very new to gradle. Also if I'm seeing all classes in the jar, this can't be a dependency thing right?

Comment: I just edited my answer to change from compile to testRuntime. Try with testRuntime in your project.

Comment: Doh! did not realize that, yup that was it, thank you RaGe